# Replicate Java's getTime() in PHP

Tags: java, php, date

I have the following code in java which returns `549255600000`:

```
Date date = new Date(87, 4, 29);
long micro = date.getTime();
System.out.println(micro);
```

The following in PHP returns another value `546663600000`:

```
var_dump(strtotime('1987-04-29') * 1000)
```

I need a php function that returns the same of the Java code. Why it's different?

The above in Java prints the same of PHP:

```
  // date variable is the same
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  utilDate = formatter.parse(date);
  System.out.println("utilDate: " + utilDate.getTime());
```

Maybe the error is in the first java snippet.

Comment: I get a whole other number: http://3v4l.org/BOJFq - are you certain your input is correct?

Comment: @Bulk I need to get 549255600000

Comment: Keep in mind that some languages work with zero-based months. So for some the month range is from 0 to 11, for other languages it is from 1 to 12. So just check this to be sure if this is correct for Java and PHP

Comment: Yes @ndsmyter just tried it with a timestamp converter. the 546663600000 something is 1978-05-29. So the constructor for the date in Java seems to start with 0 for january

Comment: see also here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of now is: time zones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @ndsmyter the problem here is that the first java snippet should be 3 in the month parameter because the month is 0 to 11. So it will output `546663600000` as in the PHP snippet.

```
Date date = new Date(87, 3, 29);
long micro = date.getTime();
System.out.println(micro);
```

Comment: You're welcome ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537488/replicate-javas-gettime-in-php#comment47227767_29537488